# Spritekit and swift 2 - overlapping sprites

Tags: sprite-kit, sprite, swift2

I need to create a road(one simple horizontal line)  using SpriteKit, so i have four obstacles to put anywhere position on the road. These obstacles will be in a "shelf" and I have to drag them to the road.

How can i do that using SpriteKit and the new Swift2 ?

PS: I'm beginner on spriteKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you meant to make some SKSpriteNode (road) as you say and put another SKSpriteNode onto that road. (Further I assume that you already have sprite nodes of the road and one obstacle)

define the property of your gameScene:

```
let roadAndObstaclesLayer: SKNode!
```

then in didMoveToView you have to add the road SKSpriteNode and obstacle SKSpriteNode to that layer. Your have to make either spawn obstacle method or you have to make position of your obstacles by yourself.
In general it would be like:

```
roadAndObstaclesLayer = SKNode()
roadAndObstaclesLayer.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetHeight(frame) / 4) // position of your layer
roadAndObstaclesLayer.addChild(road)  //child road is added
roadAndObstaclesLayer.zPosition = 0   //zPosition of the layer in the scene
road.zPosition = 0  //zPosition of the child (road) in the layer

roadAndObstaclesLayer.addChild(obstacle) //child obstacle is added
obstacle.zPosition = 1 //zPosition of the child (obstacle) in the layer above child rode

addChild(roadAndObstaclesLayer)  //child of the scene is added
```

As you understand this is an example of single obstacle that is on the road. Your obstacle and road would be placed at the same place but if you want to make some difference of the positions so you have to describe the position of obstacle separately.

As well you can place road and obstacle in different layers or in scene itself separately so their position would be independent according to each other. So in other words it depends on what do you want see at the end.

Hope it helps.